# Discord.js Delete the trigger message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am new to Discord.js, and I'm looking to delete the trigger message after the bot responds to it, i.e:

*!example*

*Example bot response*

*Bot deletes the "!example" message*

Comment: Take a look at the [example](https://discord.js.org/#/) on the docs homepage. The `msg` parameter in the `client.on('message', ...)` handler is the received message, which you can then delete with `msg.delete()`. Note that the bot needs the Manage Messages permission.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`message.delete()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete).

Example:

```js
client.on('message', (msg) => {

// your code

msg.delete()
   .then(() => console.log('Deleted message'))
   .catch(err => console.log(err))

});
```

Comment: Alright, but should I include it in my handler? I.e    ... } else if (message.content === `!example`) {
  client.commands.get('example').execute(message); ...

Comment: I don't know how your handler looks but I'm using the `.delete()` function in my **message event**, after the **execute** function

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: `<Message>.delete()` in your command.

<Message> refers to the [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object.

Find more about message.delete() [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)