# how do I use discord.js purge in a bot?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a bot and I am trying to make it happen that every time i type in a command it does the command and deletes the message afterwards.

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=delete You will need special permissions to delete other people's messages

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following in order to delete the users message.

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  message.channel.send("I'm doing something!");
  await message.delete();
});

client.login("your-token");
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67967771/discord-js-delete-the-trigger-message/67972396#67972396) similar question.